# How to refresh citation drop-down list after adding an entry to the current bib

Tags: bibliographies, texstudio

[TeXstudio 2.10.4, Win7]
Building the document is working fine, with all references correctly placed.
However, I am adding entries to my main.bib file in TeXstudio as I'm writing and presently, I have to save my work, exit TeXstudio and reload everything before I can see the new entries in the `\cite` drop-down list.  I've tried deleting all the miscellaneous generated files, including the pdf itself, but this doesn't help.
Is there a way of refreshing without having to exit?

Comment: Sounds like a bug of TeXStudio. Have you looked at there Issues on Sourceforge?

Comment: I've now posted the question there, but wasn't able to find anything in their forum.  I thought I'ld post here as this is where I find most help on LaTeX related issues.